# Creating a custom facebook feed on a website

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to find some information/documentation on creating a custom Facebook feed for any website. (Custom css etc) but there is nearly nothing to find. I want to read posts from a public facebook page and display them on my website in an owl carousel.

The only guide I found was outdated since facebooks developers page completely changed and the other guides are all for Wordpress.

Does anyone know any good guides, or can anyone help me in the good direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example code and information can be found in the API reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#read

I suggest using an App Token on the server, it is valid forever. If you don´t know about the different Tokens, here are some links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Side Note: To get pictures, you can use the `full_picture` field: `/page-id/feed?fields=full_picture`

Comment: So I need the permission of a Facebook page manager to get the access token. Can a user grant that permission if they are an assigned admin, and not the creator of a Facebook page?

Comment: what? no, where did you read that? i said "APP" token, not page token, just read the links in my answer.

Comment: I need to read a feed from someones facebook page (not my own), so I'm going to need the page access token right? It says I have to get the permission from a page manager.

Comment: then you can only use an app token anyway. you can only get a page token if you manage the page. again, please read my answer and all the links in it. they explain in detail what tokens there are and how to generate them.

Comment: I got it to work, do you have any idea on how to also get the image from a post? When I show all the data from /feed/ it shows only the post date, post content and posted by, I don't see any image value while some posts have an image.

Comment: take a look at the docs about posts to get an idea about the possible fields: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/post

Comment: I did but that field is not present when I look at the JSON string. Not even on pageid/photos there it only shows the image ID and created date.

Comment: try this: page-id/feed?fields=full_picture

Comment: Thanks! I just saw the answer on my other question, I will accept it in 3 minutes. Now I know how to correctly use the facebook fields.